# Phonegap : Camera not working in android kitkat

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing an App in Android for camera application. I add the camera using cordova plugin

**config.xml**

```
 <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

code for taking Picture

```
 function snapPicture () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail, 
        { quality: 100,  
          sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
          encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          correctOrientation: false,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true
         });


    //A callback function when snapping picture is success.
    function onSuccess (imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById ('picture');
        alert("path : "+imageData);
        image.src =  imageData;
    }

    //A callback function when snapping picture is fail.
    function onFail (message) {
        alert ('Error occured: ' + message);
    }
}
```

The code is working fine in all Android version expect Android Kitkat. In Kitkat am getting the response as "**Error capturing image**"

can any tell me what is the issue in Kitkat
Thanks in Advance ...!

Comment: Which cordova version do you use? Check it in terminal via typing `cordova -v` and please also the version of cordova android in your project. To check that run `cordova platform version` inside your project directory.

Comment: @ Sithys am using cordova 4.2.0. and trying to run in kitkat  4.4.4

Comment: i need the platform version of cordova android please. There were many issues at kitkat because of the new implemented webview. So... i think, you're discovering one of the already fixed issues. Run your cmd as administrator on windows, or start with `sudo` on mac. `npm update -g cordova`

Comment: @Sithys  so you says that update the cordova for solving this issuer ..

Comment: Thats what i said. You don't need to write a comment for such things if you haven't more details than you're comment before.

Comment: @ Sithys am using cordova 4.2.0 and platform is android 3.6.4

Comment: Than update your cordova and your platforms inside your project like i already said.

Comment: @Sithys i update the cordova  now it is 5.1.1 . Now if i try to capture the image it is not calling even "success" or "fail" method

Comment: Did you try to get the log / error / warn in GapDebug? I got your problem, just a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83194/discussion-between-binil-surendran-and-sithys).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake inside your code. `destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,` will not work. Change that line to `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,` instead and it'll run. Here's your full working code:

```
function snapPicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
             sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
             mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
             destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
             encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
             correctOrientation: false,
             saveToPhotoAlbum: true
             })


             //A callback function when snapping picture is success.
             function onSuccess (imageData) {
                 var image = document.getElementById ('picture');
                 alert("path : "+imageData);
                 image.src =  imageData;
             }

             //A callback function when snapping picture is fail.
             function onFail (message) {
                 alert ('Error occured: ' + message);
             }
    }
```

I recommend you to use [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) to Debug your Applications.

Comment: I tried the code , but still i Am getting the error as "Error capturing image ". this error only in Android Kitkat

Comment: Did you try to use GapDebug like i mentioned?