# cordova phonegap camera API example not working in android platform. why?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, camera

I am new in phonegap and I am having problems with camera API.

I copied the code from phonegap Camera API documentation and it is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/cordova.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("this is device ready 12");
        pictureSource=Camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=Camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
        // alert(imageData);
        alert("success data");
        // Get image handle
        //
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI
        // alert(imageURI);
  alert("success uri");
        // Get image handle
        //
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
        alert("success capture");
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        Camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
        alert("success edit");
        // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image        as base64-encoded string
        Camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        alert("success get photo");
        Camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

</script>
 <  /head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
     <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button>       <br>
   <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo       Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
     <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
     <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.phonegap.helloworld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
          <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"    android:supportsRtl="true">
          <activity    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
              <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this is my config.xml (I just include the important part here):

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.3.0" />
```

and I have tried so many links in my research but none of them helped. these links include: [phonegap community](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/camera_example_from_cordova_docs_not_working_on_android) and some other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398916/phonegap-camera-not-working-in-android-kitkat). 
in my app DeviceReady event fires but the buttons wont work and I checked it enters the capturePhoto function and capturePhotoEdit but it doesn't enter getPhoto. any idea why? what am I missing?

my guess is that I might not install the plugin properly. but I removed the platform and plugin once then add them again using the [phonegap documentation here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

if you need more or less info for answering let me now.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**2)AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.example.Camera" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="Camera" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

**3) config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.Camera" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <name>Camera</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

hello, try this as your code changes and also if any problem then tell me ok.

Comment: it is a big project could you just point out the difference ?

Comment: ok but first of all tell me you are add plugin manually ? please add plugin through command line using cmd. its better way. you know how to install through using cmd ?

Comment: yes i did and I do know how. it's through the command:
'cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera'

Answer (score 0):

so I solved it. as you can see everything is perfect in androidManifest.xml and in config.xml but my mistake was adding cordova.js to my directory manually what I should do was give the tag the address of my www folder because the plugins would add to cordova.js at build. so here is my code: note that the html in this code is actually in www/htmls so my cordova.js address is ../cordova.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
        // console.log(imageData);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI
        // console.log(imageURI);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
        // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
 <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
 <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo    Library</button><br>
 <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo    Album</button><br>
 <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
 <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

I had seen it before but i thought it is not relevant, and simply ignored it.

hope this help someone else.